# App updates for users on older iOS after updating minimum iOS version

Tags: ios, app-store

I’m working an update for an app that will increase the minimum iOS version that the app supports, and I’m trying to determine whether users on an older version of iOS will still automatically receive updates for the last supported version.

For instance, suppose I released version 1.8 of my app last week, which supported iOS 12 and above. This week, I release version 2.0, which increases the minimum iOS version to 13. Would a user running iOS 12 who hadn’t yet installed version 1.8 (which was the last to support iOS 12) still see version 1.8 in the App Store updates area, and receive the update automatically if they have automatic updates enabled? (I know they wouldn’t see or receive 2.0, since that requires a newer version of iOS.)

TLDR: Do users on an older version of iOS still receive updates as far as the highest app version that supports their version of iOS, without having to go manually download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from Apple developer support seeming to confirm that updates remain available:

> If you are dropping support for iOS12, as long as the latest version
> that is compatible with iOS12 has not been removed in App Store
> Connect, users who are running iOS12 will be able to update to the
> latest version that is compatible with their device.